# Angular Dispacement, velocity, acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

What is the effect of angular velocity and acceleration on circular motion as they both have direction so what is its effect?

Answer (score 1):

Well, calling angular velocity as an effect on circular motion might not be exactly accurate. It's more like a property of any body **showcasing or exhibiting** circular motion.
So to be precise, one can figure out the angular velocity of a body if it is known to be moving in a circle or a curve.

As for the relation of acceleration to circular motion, it's pretty interesting one. A very well known fact is that if a body starts to change its direction of motion, there **must** be a force (and hence an acceleration) acting **perpendicular** to the direction of motion. There may be other forces parallel to the direction of motion also, but that doesn't contribute to a change in direction.

Hope this helps!

**Note:** If the motion isn't exactly circular and more like a smooth curve, terms like instantaneous angular velocity and instantaneous velocity are used.